# Filtering content by whether field contains a value

Tags: python, csv, pandas, filtering

In my original code that processes csv files I was skipping the data from rows that contained a certain value:

```
df = df[df["ORGANIZATION"]!="Org1"]
```

Now I need to skip data that **contains** that value. The following determines if it contains the value...

```
df = df[df["ORGANIZATION"].str.contains("Org1")]
```

But how do I negate that to hide those values? Some values may be "Org1 - Dave" or "Org1 - Lisa". How do I skip data that contains "Org1" somewhere in the value?

I've been searching but can't phrase my question properly to find the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `~` to negate your boolean Series:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"ORGANIZATION": ["Org1", "Org1 - Dave", "Org1 - Lisa", "Org2 - Bob", "Org3 - Sally"]})
>>> df
   ORGANIZATION
0          Org1
1   Org1 - Dave
2   Org1 - Lisa
3    Org2 - Bob
4  Org3 - Sally

[5 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df[df["ORGANIZATION"].str.contains("Org1")]
  ORGANIZATION
0         Org1
1  Org1 - Dave
2  Org1 - Lisa

[3 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df[~df["ORGANIZATION"].str.contains("Org1")]
   ORGANIZATION
3    Org2 - Bob
4  Org3 - Sally
[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

Note that you can also use `groupby` to divide the frame up:

```
>>> gg = df.groupby(df["ORGANIZATION"].str.contains("Org1"))
>>> for k,g in gg:
...     print k
...     print g
...     
False
   ORGANIZATION
3    Org2 - Bob
4  Org3 - Sally

[2 rows x 1 columns]
True
  ORGANIZATION
0         Org1
1  Org1 - Dave
2  Org1 - Lisa

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that these values are case sensitive. Can I convert the `df["ORGANIZATION"]` column to convert everything to uppercase and then search for the value?

Comment: If you want to make that column uppercase, you can do `df["ORGANIZATION"] = df["ORGANIZATION"].str.upper()`.  If you only want to do a contains search that doesn't case about case, you can do `.str.contains("Org1", case=False)`.